# Perl. Regex not matching desired when using {x,y} metacharacter

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to work with `{x,y}` meta character, so please help to understand why

```
1. 'Hello' =~ /\w{2,}/; # Returns true. while..

2. 'Hello' =~ /\w{,6}/; # ..returns false ??!
```

`\w{2,}` stands for *'match [0-9A-Za-z_] character at least 2 times'*

`\w{,6}` stands for *'match [0-9A-Za-z_] character at most 6 times'*

If I'm reading this correct? So why the second doesn't match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [perlre documentation -- Quantifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quantifiers), only `*`, `+`, `?`, `{n}`, `{n,}`, `{n,m}` are recognized:

> The following standard quantifiers are recognized:
>
> ```
> *           Match 0 or more times
> +           Match 1 or more times
> ?           Match 1 or 0 times
> {n}         Match exactly n times
> {n,}        Match at least n times
> {n,m}       Match at least n but not more than m times
> ```

-> `/{,6}/` matches `'{,6}'` literally.

---

Use `/\w{0,6}/` or `/\w{1,6}/` instead according to your need.

Comment: Upvoted for reference to quantifiers, which is exactly the issue here. Teach a @sapiens to fish.

Answer (score 3):

The first argument to the `{n,m}` expression is required.  See the `perlre` man page, for example:

```
       {n}         Match exactly n times
       {n,}        Match at least n times
       {n,m}       Match at least n but not more than m times
```

A pattern like `{,m}` is not recognized. If you explicitly give the first argument as 1 it works:

```
       print 'Hello' =~ /\w{1,6}/;
```

generates "1".

Answer (score 3):

Actually:

`\w{n,m}` means match alphanumeric least n times, but at most m times.

`\w{n,}` means match alphanumeric n or more times.

`\w{n}` means match alphanumeric exactly n times.

*However*:

`\w{,m}` means match alphanumeric followed by the literal `{,m}`. This is because the n is required; you must specify the first argument to the `{n,m}` expression.